# When a Google Search Console removal request expires, could that content return to the Google index?

Tags: google-search-console, content, url-removal

I had content removed using the google search console and removal requests because the links and images were outdated. It has expired on some of them now.

Does that meant the links could return onto Google? I’ve checked other answers and it seems to just be that there is nothing left to remove. Does expired content mean it is gone for good and won’t appear again?

Comment: When Google Search Console says it "expired," it isn't talking about the content, it is talking about the removal request.

Comment: So if the removal request has expired does that mean there is a chance that the content itself will return on google index?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this means that the links can return to Google. From Google's knowledge base:

> A successful request lasts only about 90 days. After that, your information can appear on Google search results

Here's how to make the removal permanent:

> ## Make removal permanent
>
> The Remove URLs tool provides only a temporary removal. To remove content or a URL from Google search permanently you must take one or more of the following additional actions:
>
> - **Remove or update the actual content from your site** (images, pages, directories) and make sure that your web server returns either a 404 (Not Found) or 410 (Gone) HTTP status code. Non-HTML files (like PDFs) should be completely removed from your server. (Learn more about HTTP status codes)
> - **Block access to the content**, for example by requiring a password.
> - **Indicate that the page should not be indexed** using the noindex meta tag. This is less secure than the other methods.
>
> *[Remove URLs Tool - Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en)*

The easiest and least intrusive thing to do, assuming you want the content to stay up but just not indexed in Google, is to go with the third option - [use the `meta noindex` tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710).

Comment: Ahh thank you. My request expired earlier then 90 days and I did hear that if it expired earlier it is because there is nothing left to be indexed (I.e changing content/outdated content) thus won’t appear in the search anyway. Oh well I’ll try the other methods. Thank you